# How to extend Eclipse's compare context menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, compare, contextmenu

I want to create a plugin that displays additional information about Eclipse's compare results. For example, clicking a difference in Eclipse will bring up additional meta-information in my new view about who made the change, when it was made, what are the related changes, etc. I've got everything else figured out except how to call the view from the compare editor. I am thinking of using a context menu.

I was able to implement a context menu for the text editor. I used a targetID of targetID="#TextEditorContext and the action to inherit from IViewActionDelegate. But somehow the compare editor is not the same as the normal text editor. What targetID should I use? Is this even possible? Or if someone has a better idea than context menu, do share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to add additional commands (Handlers) to the compare view's context menu using the popup menu id `popup:org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditor?after=additions`